# Link error after updating next js to v9 - Parameter 'url' must be string, not undefined

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-router, next.js, vercel

I recently updated my **nextJs** project to version 9 . I use **next-routes** package with exporting like bottom.

```
const routes = require('next-routes');

module.exports = routes()
    //******************************** structure of routes => {nameOfRoute, pattern  of route, page name inside pages folder } ************
    .add('homepage', '/', 'index')
    // **************************** Profile routes *******************************************************
    .add('dashboard', '/dashboard', 'dashboard/index')
    .add('profile_navigation', '/dashboard/profile/navigation', 'dashboard/profile/navigation')
    .add('profile_userInfo', '/dashboard/profile/user-information', 'dashboard/profile/userInfo')
    .add('profile_education', '/dashboard/profile/education', 'dashboard/profile/education')
    .add('profile_sendCV', '/dashboard/profile/send-cv', 'dashboard/profile/sendCV')
    .add('profile_skills', '/dashboard/profile/skills', 'dashboard/profile/skills')
    .add('profile_honorAndResearch', '/dashboard/profile/honor-and-research', 'dashboard/profile/honorAndResearch')
    .add('profile_language', '/dashboard/profile/language-skill', 'dashboard/profile/language')
    .add('profile_workExperience', '/dashboard/profile/work-experience', 'dashboard/profile/workExperience')
    .add('profile_profilePreview', '/dashboard/profile/preview', 'dashboard/profile/profileView')
    .add('profile_favoriteJobs', '/dashboard/profile/favorite-jobs', 'dashboard/profile/favoriteJobs')
    .add('profile_courses', '/dashboard/profile/courses', 'dashboard/profile/courses')
```

There is a problem when i use **Link** like this

```
import { Link } from '../../routes';
<Link route="dashboard">
   <a>Some text</a>
</Link>
```

I get the error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Parameter 'url' must be a string, not undefined
at Url.push../node_modules/url/url.js.Url.parse (url.js:112)
at urlParse (url.js:106)
at Url.push../node_modules/url/url.js.Url.resolve (url.js:443)
at urlResolve (url.js:439)
at Link.getHref (link.js:8)
at Link.handleRef (link.js:8)
at ref (link.js:13)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's ok for me when I add `prefetch={false}` to Link.

```
<Link href="YOUR_LINK" prefetch={false} />
```

See more explaination here: https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/8555

Comment: I use so many routes defined in **routes/index.ts** and i use *route* props . with using just href it's ok